# Where can I find the official version of MiKTeX to download safely?

Tags: installing, miktex, online

I just tried downloading a newer version of MiKTeX from the MiKTeX site and a huge amount of sketchy junk, including shop to win and blekko seemed to come with it, scaring me off.  Is this safe? And can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Exaclty what did you download? From http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup, if I choose the Basic Installer I get exactly that.

Comment: Thanks.  I clicked on the download >> on the rhs of that page, and it scared me off.  This looks good.

Comment: I'd always ignore the adverts: I'm sure they pay for the work, but I don't trust them ;-)

Comment: @mike I tried to specify your question a bit, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 4):

The download files you can get from the side [MiKTeX 2.9 Setup](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup) *(Joseph Wright already posted this link in his comment)*.

If you chose to download the basic installer, then there’s a selection of mirrors possible. Perhaps the preselected one have sent the adverts.